# Обязателен ли закрывающий тег  при использовании HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Обязателен ли закрывающий тег </html> при использовании HTML5? Если обязателен, то что будет, если я не закрою его?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот тег используется один раз на странице. Стоит из-за него дискуссию поднимать. Лучше поставить. Много места не займет.

Answer (score 3):

да.

> Если обязателен, то что будет если я
> не закрою его?

Большая часть браузеров закроет его за тебя.

Comment: Ну если учитывать, что все современные браузеры закрывают </html> сами, то я могу не закрывать его. Правильно?

Comment: @SkaZzzz ну зOчем пЕсать граматна?? проше пЕсать с ашыбками, так ведь быстрее нОмного!

Comment: Проще вывернуть наизнанку всё, чем уточнить для чего это необходимо? СчЕтайтИ вИ прОвы, пЕсать так гАраздо быстрее...

Comment: @SkaZzzz для чего это необходимо ? правила такие. точка

Comment: Ломаю стереотип... В общем, суть я понял. И сделал для себя выводы. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: >для чего это необходимо? 

обратите внимание на последнюю строку в этом ответе: "**Большая часть** браузеров закроет его за тебя"

Именно большая часть, а не все. А было бы неплохо, если бы код вашего сайта был валидным везде. Кроме того, скорее всего (тут могу ошибаться, но могу и не ошибаться), подобное поведение (автоматическое закрытие тега) не входит в стандарт, а потому завтра эта "большая часть браузеров" может отказаться от такого поведения, или появится какой-нибудь другой браузер, который не станет делать этого за вас.

Answer (score 2):

В html 5 теги html, body, head стали вообще необязательны, насколько я помню. Но это считается хорошим тоном, поэтому стоит их все-таки писать.

Если вы не закроете, скорее всего, на это ругнется валидатор, и если ваш код придет смотреть другой верстальщик, он будет плеваться на это. =)

Не нужно г*вно-кодить =)

Comment: использовал http://validator.w3.org/ с </html> и без </html> одинаково валиден. Или вы имеете ввиду какой-то другой валидатор?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, любой html файл, является так же правильным  xml документом. А там корневой элемент обязателен. То есть тег, в который вложены все остальные. А так же там все  теги должны быть закрыты. Так что если вы хотите, чтобы ваш html-страница была совместима с xml технологиями, то используйте тег html и обязательно закрывайте его. Да и поисковикам легче будет работать с такой станицей.